# iAds not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have implemented the following code:

```
 -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

And published the app to the app store. Ads are not showing up in the app store app nor am I getting any information in iTunes Connect when I go to view iAd information. Is this code right and the only code I have to put? In the storyboard, I have the iAd at the bottom of the screen connected to the delegate and I also have this in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {
```

(Showing that I have imported the iAd Framework and have the `ADBannerViewDelegate`)

Comment: What is `banner`? An IBOutlet? Is it linked? Do the ads run correctly during your testing?

Comment: Banner is the ad itself, I believe. The ads ran great during testing.

Comment: Can you show how you init banner object?

Comment: Are you in a country that supports iAds? for example in Sweden iAds is not supported and is not working.

Comment: I'm in the US. And…I should probably init the ads, shouldn't I?

Comment: @VietHung if I init the ads `adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];`, would that fixed my problem?

Comment: You should show full code, it's easy for everyone to run and find out the reason

Comment: @VietHung that's all the code regarding iAds.

Comment: Your question is just a part of your code. Create an example for everyone just press RUN. It's easy to detect your problem. Everyone is NOT beside you, not imagine what you're doing. Make your question clearly, and you will get the answer